# Checking for email in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a problem when checking if email allready exists in the database.

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once("connection.php");
$handler = new Connection;
$handler = $handler->connect();

$email = $_POST['email'];

$check = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM emailcollector WHERE email=':mail'");
$check->execute(array(':mail' => $email));


if($check->rowCount > 0){
  header("Location: yes.php");
}else{
  header("Location: no.php");
}
?>
```

Im using a pdo connection to the database. When i run the code it allways says that it does not exist. Im kinda new to this. Thanks for any help

Comment: Remove quotes form here `email=':mail'` it would be `email=:mail`

Comment: @Saty , still does not work

Comment: Now what error you got??

Comment: Don't get an error, it just jumps to no.php so it does the $check->rowCount  is equal to 0, meaning that the email does not exist.

Comment: Yes may be . Check email is exist in your database or not??

Comment: It does exist. I need it to go to yes.php if it exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rowCount` is a function and not a property. Therefore you have to call it like this, *Note the `()`*

```
if($check->rowCount() > 0){
```

Answer (score 2):

In your SQL, remove the quotes around `':mail'`

```
$check = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM emailcollector WHERE email=:mail");
```

PDO placeholder do not require any quotes, even if the value is a string. By using quotes, you are essentially doing the below, which as you can see isn't right.

```
SELECT * FROM emailcollector WHERE email="'mail@mail.com'"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible issue with [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):**

For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

Comment: You can read the docs page i linked. Possible solutions are shown.